# pycharm adds garbage to remote path, causing file not found error when using remote interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, remote-access

Hello and happy new year. I was able to a remote host with pycharm and I see and am able to open files from a linux machine. Additionally, I was able to set up a remote interpreter which I can use on local files. The problem is when I use that interpreter with remote files, I keep getting a file does not exist error.

When I bring up the run configuration, the script path appears to have garbage which I don't know where it's coming from. I see the same garbage in the script path when I run the script.

[image]

Anyone have any ideas what could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem. I guess one have to have the files in a local copy. What you call 'garbage' I think it's a kind of hash for a temporary copy of the file which you have locally anyways.. So just use local files, and update the remote location automatically

UPDATE

I made it work selecting the right configuration beside the `run` button in PyCharm. The IDE was generating additional configurations and I had your garbage results. Once I selected my manually made original configuration, all worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Change your working directory in Configurations